# Is it possible to set a column width for a Java output?

Tags: java, text, output, width

Good morning all, I am trying to work out the basics of Java and am trying to get a string to print with a specified column width in both the command line and console. Its a string of text so I don't want to truncate the data that doesn't fit, instead I want it to print on the next line if it doesn't fit within the specified width. Is this possible? I have looked at various things using formatter but have had no success.

Comment: Short answer: nope.  Write your own output filter if you really need this, it won't be hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too difficult.
You can do something like this:

```
public static void printLimit(Object obj, int width) {

    String val = obj.toString();

    if (val.length() > width && width > 0) {
        System.out.println(val.substring(0, width));
        printLimit(val.substring(width, val.length()), width);
    } else {
        System.out.println(val);
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming the console has a fixed width font

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was over thinking things but as you have shown, it's nice and simple.